# Kubernetes rollout give 503 error when switching web pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I'm running this command:

```
kubectl set image deployment/www-deployment VERSION_www=newImage
```

Works fine.  But there's a 10 second window where the website is 503, and I'm a perfectionist.

**How can I configure kubernetes to wait for the image to be available before switching the ingress?**

I'm using the nginx ingress controller from here:

```
gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
```

And this yaml for the web server:

```
# Service and Deployment
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: www-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http-port
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http-port
  selector:
    app: www
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: www-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: www
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myapp/www
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: http-port
        name: www
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http-port
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/env-volume
          name: config
          readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: cloud.docker.com-pull
      volumes:
      - name: config
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: www.sh
            mode: 256
            path: env.sh
          secretName: env-secret
```

The Docker image is based on a [node.js server image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/4.5/slim/Dockerfile).

`/healthz` is a file in the webserver which returns `ok`  I thought that liveness probe would make sure the server was up and ready before switching to the new version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

within the [Pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/) it's defined that:

> The default state of Liveness before the initial delay is Success.

To make sure you don't run into issues better configure the `ReadinessProbe` for your Pods too and consider to configure `.spec.minReadySeconds` for your Deployment.

You'll find details in the [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments) documentation